# How to Place an Image on Top of a Background Image

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to place an image on top of a background image. The background is contained within a div placed on the bottom of the containing div. I want to place an image on the bottom right-hand corner on top of the background image that's placed bottom center.

I have tried to use two background images but was unable to place the image on top of the repeating div without having issues with placement on mobile, because the text area shrinks and moves the image below the container.

I tried placing the image in-line but am unable to have it appear on top of the background.

Any ideas on what the best method would be to do this?

```css
.gradient-bg.slide {
  background: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/d/b/5/1206555848388219874chlopaya_Bird.svg.med.png") no-repeat left top, linear-gradient(#ffcd74, #f8981d);
  /*background: #ffcd74;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffcd74 29%, #f8981d 78%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffcd74 29%,#f8981d 78%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffcd74 29%,#f8981d 78%);*/
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffcd74', endColorstr='#f8981d', GradientType=0);
}

.slide_cloud {
  background: url("https://preview.ibb.co/cyvOLv/harris_relativity_cloud_footer.png") no-repeat bottom center;
  background-size: inherit;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo-image {
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/WikiSpecies_notext.svg/300px-WikiSpecies_notext.svg.png") no-repeat bottom right;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-bg slide">
  <div class="slide slide_cloud">
    <h2>Generic Header</h2>
    <div class="logo-image">
    </div>
    <div class="slide-content">
      <div class="text">Generic text.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hello @hungerstar, I have included a sample

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want the page to look like.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I want the logo image to be positioned in the bottom right corner of the div, on top of the cloud image in the sample.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position?v=control

Comment: I have already used background position for all 3 images, and i am still unable to have the logo image appear on top of the bottom cloud image.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have explained I'm assuming this to be your desired layout.

```
<div class="cloudbg">
<div class="bird">
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/d/b/5/1206555848388219874chlopaya_Bird.svg.med.png" height="75px" width="100px">
<h2>Generic Header</h2>
<div class="content">
<br> Generic Text
</div>
</div>
<div class="logo">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/WikiSpecies_notext.svg/300px-WikiSpecies_notext.svg.png" height="50px">
</div>
```

I have used absolute positioning in the above code to place the objects. To get the header to come in the same line make it an inline element as shown below. Make sure to make changes to the values according to your needs.

```
.bird h2 {
display: inline;
vertical-align: top;
}

.cloudbg {
background: 
url("https://preview.ibb.co/cyvOLv/harris_relativity_cloud_footer.png") no-
repeat bottom;
height: 350px;
text-align: center;
}

.bird {
display: inline;
float: left;
}

.content {
display: block;
}

.logo {
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: 2px;
right: 5px;
}
```

Here is a working solution- https://jsfiddle.net/jts9owh4/

Comment: Thank you for providing me with this. I realized the reason why the two background images wouldn't allow one to come in over the other was because it seems that css prioritizes the first image. So by default the first background image i specified would always appear above the others.